# Table height not same in browsers

Tags: html, css

Have following code with tables, but the table height is not the same in different browser and when printing. See picture difference with column 1,2  and 3. I need every table the same height with or without lines.

thanx

Martijn

[image: Table layout]

css:

```
.prn_outer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #333; 
}

.prn_inner {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 160px;
    border: 1px solid #333; 
}

.prn_row_top {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #333; 
}

.prn_row_bottom {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #333;
}
```

html:

```
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="prn_outer">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td width="20%"><table border="0" height="160" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="prn_inner">
              <tr>
                <td height="18">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="18" class="prn_row_bottom">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="18">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="18" class="prn_row_bottom">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="18">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="18" class="prn_row_bottom">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="18">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="18">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          <td width="20%"><table border="0" height="160" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="prn_inner">
              <tr>
                <td height="18">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="18" class="prn_row_bottom">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="18">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="18" class="prn_row_bottom" >&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="18">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="18" class="prn_row_bottom">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="18">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="18">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          <td width="20%"><table border="0" height="160" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="prn_inner">
              <tr>
                <td height="18" class="prn_row_bottom">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="134">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          <td width="20%"><table width="100%" height="160" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td height="158">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          <td width="20%"><table width="100%" height="160" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td height="158">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not accounting for the additional pixel height for borders when you nest your tables.

```
td table.prn_inner {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 158px <----- this can't stay at 160px, if it's nested
    border: 1px solid; 
}
```

You also have some conflicts with your table params in your HTML vs your CSS. You can clean that up by moving all your table declarations to your CSS (it'll make your HTML a lot easier to read too).

```
CSS
table { width:100%; }
td { width:20% }
.prn_inner td { height:18px }

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><table class="prn_inner">
              <tr>
                <td>table in a table</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note: Best practice = tables are for data. Your nested tables elude to poor choice in layout/design.

Comment: Thanx both, have made it with the div solution, you are right Dawson

Answer (score 0):

did you tried putting prn_outer height aswell? for printing you could use @media print and play there with the correct format you need and will apply only for printing